# "Network Error" and "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED" when making login request with Axios

Tags: vue.js, axios

I'm developing a Vue.js project and using Axios library to make a login request. However, when I attempt to login, I see the following error message in the browser's developer tools:

```
login.vue:51 Login request error:
AxiosError {
  message: "Network Error",
  name: "AxiosError",
  code: "ERR_NETWORK",
  config: { ... },
  request: XMLHttpRequest,
  ...
}
xhr.js:251 POST http://192.168.56.1:8080/api/login net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

I have confirmed that the server is running and I can access it via http://192.168.56.1:8080. However, when I try to send the login request, I'm encountering a network error and connection refused issue.

Here is the code I'm using to make the login request in the login.vue component:

```
<script>
import axios from 'axios';
export default {
  methods: {
    login() {
  const data = {
    username: this.username,
    password: this.password
  };
 
  // const params = new URLSearchParams(data);
  this.$axios.post('/api/login', data)
    .then(response => {
      const resData = response.data;
      if (resData.code === 1) {
        alert('success');
        console.log('userinfo:', resData.data);
        this.goToHomePage(); 
      } else {
        alert('error');
      }
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Login request error:', error);
    });
},
```

I have tried the following troubleshooting steps, but the issue persists:

Verified that the server is running and listening on the correct port.
Checked network configurations to ensure there are no firewalls or proxy settings blocking the connection to the server.
Tried in different network environments, but the same problem occurs.
I'm looking for a solution to successfully connect to the server and complete the login request. Any further details or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: This is usually an issue with the backend.  Could be a lot of different things so you'll need to include code showing how your backend is setup and running as well as relevant route code for `/login`.